# Update rows of dataframe using columns from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

df1:
[image]

The other one with values is like this:

df2:

[image]

I want to upate df1 values with df2 and the desired result is:

[image]

I don't know if it matter but df1 has more columns than what i showed here.
I tried some solutions using unstack, join and melt, but couldn't make them work.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Hi Adolf! It will be much easier for others to answer your question if you post your sample dataframes as code rather than as images. Also, try posting what you've tried and what went wrong, rather than just saying they don't work. That way people can make concrete suggestions.

Comment: Just stack df2: `df2.stack().reset_index(level=1)`